# How to add custom directory to "Tests" scope in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, ant

I'm working with Ant project, where I've added "test" directory near "src" directory. IDEA does not understand, that all classes in this directory are test classes. I want to make IDEA understand this, so it will propose to generate "Test Method", in respective "Generate" menu, for example, like it does in Maven's test directory. So, how can I make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to make it. The user has to open File -> Project structure -> Modules -> Sources Tab, select the directory he wants to make test directory and mark it as test directory using "Tests" button above directory tree.

It works in Intellij IDEA 2016.